# How do I call CSS and JS URLs from local storage on a web view page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage called webview.html.

When I come on this page, I want it to load its structure from local storage.

This is what is saved in local storage -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  

    {{META}}

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sources/template/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sources/template/css/common.css" type="text/css">


</head>

<body id="page-top">

    <div id="main-wrapper">
   
      {{CONTENT}}  

   </div>
   
   
      <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="sources/template/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="sources/template/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="sources/template/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sources/template/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script src="sources/template/js/wow.min.js"></script>
 <script src="sources/template/js/popupimage.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
   <script src="sources/template/js/creative.js"></script>
 <script src="sources/template/js/light-slider.js"></script>
<script src="sources/template/js/count.js"></script>
<script src="sources/template/js/menu.js"></script>
 <script src="sources/template/js/vertical_list.js"></script>
<script src="sources/template/js/sticky.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-One-Page-Navigation-Plugin-Page-Scroll-To-ID/jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js"></script>
<script>
 (function($){
  $(window).load(function(){
   $(".nav a").mPageScroll2id();
                                                $("#lightSlider").lightSlider();
    callCounter();
    callvertical_list();
     $(".menu2").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
  });
 })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Once this structure is loaded then I want it to load the html code which is also saved in local storage. I want it to load the code where `{{CONTENT}}` is written.

Comment: Whats the localStorage variable in which the above code is stored? and what is the name of the storage variable which has the content that needs to be loaded into the `{{CONTENT}} ` placeholder?

Comment: `section232` is the named of the key which is storing the content and `ttype` is storing the html structure, i have not coded as yet because i dont know how to process so there is no variable at the moment.

Comment: This is the json for your reference - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghfhtvz19423rqt/Screenshot%202017-05-18%2017.01.17.png?dl=0  and for the section to be loaded inside html in place of place holder - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ub481e2c1sse290/Screenshot%202017-05-18%2017.05.09.png?dl=0 , its description

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your `section232` localStorage variable:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\"en\">\r\n\r\n  <head>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    {{META}}\r\n\r\n\r\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"sources/template/css/bootstrap.min.css\" type=\"text/css\">\r\n\r\n\r\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"sources/template/css/common.css\" type=\"text/css\">\r\n\r\n\r\n  </head>\r\n\r\n  <body id=\"page-top\">\r\n\r\n    <div id=\"main-wrapper\">\r\n\r\n      {{CONTENT}}\r\n\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n\r\n    <!-- jQuery -->\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/jquery.js\"></script>\r\n\r\n    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>\r\n\r\n    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/jquery.easing.min.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/jquery.fittext.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/wow.min.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/popupimage.js\"></script>\r\n    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/creative.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/light-slider.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/count.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/menu.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/vertical_list.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"sources/template/js/sticky.js\"></script>\r\n    <script src=\"http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-One-Page-Navigation-Plugin-Page-Scroll-To-ID/jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js\"></script>\r\n    <script>\r\n      (function($) {\r\n        $(window).load(function() {\r\n          $(\".nav a\").mPageScroll2id();\r\n          $(\"#lightSlider\").lightSlider();\r\n          callCounter();\r\n          callvertical_list();\r\n          $(\".menu2\").sticky({\r\n            topSpacing: 0\r\n          });\r\n        });\r\n      })(jQuery);\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t$(document).ready(function(){\r\n\t\t\t\tif(localStorage.getItem(\"ttype\") != undefined){\r\n\t\t\t\t\t$(\"#main-wrapper\").html(localStorage.getItem(\"ttype\"));\r\n\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t});\r\n\r\n    </script>\r\n  </body>\r\n\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

Have your content ready in localStorage `ttype`.

Set the following code in *webview.html*:

```
document.write(sessionStorage.getItem("section232"));
```

Comment: i think the 1step will be `document.write(sessionStorage.getItem("ttype"));` and second step should be to place value of  key `section232` in place of the placeholder `{{content}} , isnt it  , but how ???

Comment: From what I understood from your question is, ttype = inner content and section232 = The whole page Html. Is that correct?

Comment: no reverse, i coded this on the page `<script>
var getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tType"));
document.write(getData.template_code);
</script>`  and i can see this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0wnjl5lg3fdnml/Screenshot%202017-05-18%2017.30.13.png?dl=0  , now i want to copy section232's description object at the place of placeholder, please advise

Comment: Your code to load content and place it inside the placeholder needs to be inside `template_code`. Use the JQuery `$(document).ready()` and `$("#main-wrapper").html("content of placeholder here")`

Comment: i did not get it, there are 20 sections and it depends upon user which content to load, so user may click section232 or section 233 or any other to load, how can it be inside template_code, in template_code i have added a placeholder `{{content}}` , i need to replace it with section232's description object, can you point me to some code